# Using a class and functions to keep track of user stats

Tags: c++, function, class

I am new to C++, and was wondering what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a text-based adventure game that keeps track of player stats using an add or remove function. Currently, my function does not add five points to `trust` and I am trying to get it to.

```cpp
#include "function.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double trust=100;
    editPlayer user(100);
    //asks user choice
    cin >> firstChoice;
    if (firstChoice == 1) {
        user.addTrust(trust);
        cout << trust;
```

Here is my `function.cpp` only using trust as an example:

```cpp
#include "function.h"

editPlayer::editPlayer(double trust) {
}

void editPlayer::addTrust(double trust){
    trust +=5;
}

void editPlayer::removeTrust(double trust){
    trust -=5;
}
```

And here is my `function.h`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class editPlayer{
public:
    editPlayer(double trust);
    void addTrust(double);
    void removeTrust(double);
};
```

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? This is not how classes are used.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take your `addTrust` function:

```
void editPlayer::addTrust(double trust) {
    trust += 5;
}
```

This will modify the local variable `trust`, and then the function will end. When the function ends, the life-time of the local variable `trust` also ends, and the modifications you made to it will be lost.

If you truly want to modify the argument, you need to either pass it by reference:

```
void editPlayer::addTrust(double& trust) {
    trust += 5;
}
```

Or return the new value:

```
double editPlayer::addTrust(double trust) {
    return trust + 5;
}
```

If you return the new value, you need to assign to it when calling the function:

```
trust = user.addTrust(trust);
```

---

With the above said, the code and the `editPlayer` class doesn't make much sense. There's just no need for a class `editUser` really. Possibly `addTrust` could be a non-member function, or maybe not a function at all.

The class name doesn't make sense, since it doesn't "edit" anything. And passing an argument to the constructor also doesn't make sense since the objects doesn't have any internal state (the value passed to the constructor is just discarded).

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're not storing anything specific on behalf of `user` object (an object of the `editPlayer` class.

The `cout << trust;` statement just prints a value of the `trust` local variable which you declared at the beginning: `double trust=100;`. Because this variable hasn't been changed anyhow since that initialization it is still equal to *100* and this is what you see.

In order to track any `editPlayer`-specific information the best idea is to **store** that information as a **data member** of the class `editPlayer`. You can declare a data member representing the *trust* of an object like this:

```
class editPlayer{
public:
    editPlayer(double trust);
    void addTrust(double);
    void removeTrust(double);
    double getTrust() const;  // add also this one, will be useful
private:
    double m_trust {0};   // <---- here - a data member, aka. a class field
};
```

Now you must refine you *constructor* to let it utilize the parameter which it takes and assign its value to this new data member (because currently the constructor does nothing):

```
editPlayer::editPlayer(double trust) {
    m_trust = trust;
}
```

Now in the member functions that you already have just rename the variable so that it reflects the *trust* data member (and not the parameter) which effectively will allow to update its value:

```
void editPlayer::addTrust(double trust) {
    m_trust += 5;
}

void editPlayer::removeTrust(double trust) {
    m_trust -= 5;
}

double editPlayer::getTrust() const {  // add definition of our "getter"
    return m_trust;
}
```

Finally you can replace that `cout << trust;` which we already discussed (still prints the local variable's value) with an invokation of the getter which yields `m_trust`'s value:

```
cout << user.getTrust();
```

and see the actual effect of performing the `addTrust()` operation as well as get delighted with your legitimate object-oriented program.

Answer (score 0):

In general the code you are asking can be covered by classes, member declarations and also a pinch of object oriented programming.
The internet has lots of good (and less than good) tutorials if you search for it.

I would try my luck with some of the following searches

- CPP + classes
- CPP + member declarations
- CPP + dynamic vs. static memory allocation (pointers and stuff)
- object oriented programming (OOP)

The examples on this site provide good (and short :D) examples of alot of basic concepts imho.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

Some of the topics also apply to other languages.

---

The first block with my comments:

```
#include "function.h"
using namespace std; // dont get into the habbit of using namespace std;
// the above can potentially open up for bugs

int main() 
{
  double trust=100; // This variable is declared in this scope({ ... })
  // and will get deallocated once the scope ends with the character '}'
  editPlayer user(100); // instance of editPlayer named 'user' is constructed
  //asks user choice
  cin >> firstChoice;
  if (firstChoice == 1) {
    user.addTrust(trust); // calling function on user object
    cout << trust;
}
```

Now looking at the .h file i would advocate against including headers that you dont use in the header.
For small projects it does not matter at all - but for big projects of thousands lines of code removing unused includes can speed up things.

Some would prefer forward declarations - which you can look into once you are more comfortable with the basics of cpp.

```
#include<iostream> // not used here
#include<string> // not used
using namespace std; // disaster waiting to happen

class editPlayer{
public:
    editPlayer(double trust);
    void addTrust(double);
    void removeTrust(double);
};
```

The .cpp file

```
#include "function.h"
editPlayer::editPlayer(double trust) {}

// function implementation with argument - but argument is not used - change to void fun(double) -> fun(void) OR fun()
void editPlayer::addTrust(double trust) { trust +=5; }

void editPlayer::removeTrust(double trust) { trust -=5; }
```

I did an example with class declaration and member variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// this is a class declaration
class Player
{
protected: // protected member variables
    double _trust;
public: // public interface
    Player(double trust);
    void addTrust(double);
    void removeTrust(double);

    double getTrust() const;
};

// Implementation of public interface
// notice _trust is the member defined in the class
Player::Player(double trust) : _trust(trust) {} // constructor

// example of default parameters (do note that only definition or declaration can have them)
// This means that calling the function without arguments will become 5
void Player::addTrust(double trust = 5) { _trust += trust; }
void Player::removeTrust(double trust = 5) { _trust -= trust; }
double Player::getTrust() const {return _trust; }

int main() 
{
    Player player(100); // this will invoke the constructor - and the player object will get initialised with the given state

    std::cout << player.getTrust() << std::endl;

    // variable to buffer input data into - assuming type int wrt. following if
    int firstChoice;
    //asks user choice
    std::cin >> firstChoice;
    if (firstChoice == 1) 
    {
        player.addTrust(25);
        player.addTrust();
    }
    std::cout << player.getTrust();
}
```

Happy coding !

Comment: `const double getTrust();` - `const` added before a type returned *by value* is useless. Probably you meant to put  this `const` specifier **after** the declaration to make it a *const member function*: `double getTrust() const;`.

Comment: @bloody yes either that or make it a const ref

Comment: @bloody
I did the experiement - it does compile and behaves as before when the return type is const double& getTrust(); the member variable is still NOT const.

I tried running following lines -> first a copy-assignment
 `double d = player.getTrust();
    d += 1.0;`

Taking a reference without const gives compile errors.. same does incrementing a const double
  `const double &cd = player.getTrust();
    cd += 1.0;`

Comment: What do you mean by *member variable*? You meant *member function*, didn't you?

Comment: @bloodyI was referring to the `protected: double _trust;` in my Player class as the member variable.

Comment: Oh, setting that one to `const` I didn't even consider. The program wouldn't be very useful then :) Anyway, getting back to member functions, even with `const&` return type getter I think it's still a good style to document it also as *const member function* (with 2 `const`s in a declaration :)

Comment: @bloody we can agree on that :P.. unless one designed it with immutable data structures instead.. but not sure it makes sense to do it in this particular case..

maybe for some sort of 'checkpoint' / 'save game' type of implementation